# Run Acceptance Test Play 2 - Server is not started

Tags: java, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wrote a acceptance test to in a Play! 2 Framework, my test is:

```
    @Test
public void goToIndexPageAT() {
    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>()  {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/");
            assertThat(browser.url()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:3333/activities");
            assertThat(browser.$("#title").getTexts().get(0)).isEqualTo("FitTime");
        }

    });
}
```

But when I try run this test using the command play test I got a error:

```
Test acceptenceTest.ApplicationTest.goToIndexPageAT failed: Server is not started!
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]     at play.api.test.TestServer.stop(Selenium.scala:116)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.stop(Helpers.java:308)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:338)
[error]     at acceptenceTest.ApplicationTest.goToIndexPageAT(ApplicationTest.java:17)
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this error message by using port 3333 for another application and then starting the test.

Maybe you have previously ran the test and it didn't shutdown correctly.

You can find it's PID with
netstat -onap |grep 3333 # I used it with Linux

Example output:
tcp6       0      0 :::3333    :::*      LISTEN      13173/java   aus (0.00/0/0)

Kill the process:
kill -9 13173

Comment: This approach of port work, but with two tests the execution  locked after first test:

Answer (score 0):

Here the tests:

```
@Test
public void goToIndexPageAT() {
    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>()  {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/");
            assertThat(browser.url()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:3333/activities");
            assertThat(browser.$("#title").getTexts().get(0)).isEqualTo("FitTime - Manage Your Exercises");
        }

    });
}

@Test
public void createNewActivityAT() {
     running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>()  {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/");
            browser.$("#name").text("bike");
            browser.$("#time").text("10 KM");
        }

    });
}
```

I do not know what's happening...